# How to delete all rows from table except the min & max value of column by date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table `Visitors` with the following columns

`ID`, `Visitors`, `RegDate (date & time)`

Rows: There are 4, 6, 8, 20, 11, 31, 43 Visitors with the same date (July 18) but not the same time.

Another Rows: There are 1, 5, 10, 4, 13, 15, 18, 11, 23 Visitors with the same date (July 19) but not the same time.

Something like this

```
Id  RegDate
4   2015-07-18 11:11:00.000
6   2015-07-18 11:11:01.000
8   2015-07-18 11:11:02.000
20  2015-07-18 11:11:03.000
11  2015-07-18 11:11:04.000
31  2015-07-18 11:11:05.000
43  2015-07-18 11:11:06.000
1   2015-07-19 11:11:00.000
10  2015-07-19 11:11:01.000
4   2015-07-19 11:11:02.000
13  2015-07-19 11:11:03.000
15  2015-07-19 11:11:04.000
18  2015-07-19 11:11:05.000
11  2015-07-19 11:11:06.000
23  2015-07-19 11:11:07.000
```

Here is my Query that shows the Minimum and Maximum including the date.

```
SELECT MIN(Visitors), MAX(Visitors), cast(RegDate as date) AS DATE
FROM Visitor GROUP BY cast(RegDate as date)
ORDER BY DATE
```

I want to delete all rows from the column Visitors except its Minimum and Maximum values by RegDate.

Comment: FYI, [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` to find the `Visitor` with the earliest and latest `RegDate`:

```
WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT *,
        RN_ASC = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CAST(RegDate AS DATE) ORDER BY RegDate ASC),
        RN_DESC = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CAST(RegDate AS DATE) ORDER BY RegDate DESC)
    FROM Visitor
)
DELETE FROM Cte WHERE RN_ASC > 1 AND RN_DESC > 1
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/461b1/2)

Comment: THANKS. Now I found out.
RN_ASC = RegDate.. I change ORDER BY RegDate to Visitors (column) and I got the max and mim records alive. Thanks.

Comment: Glad I could help. Feel free to accept this answer if it solves your problem. You may also edit it. =)

Answer (score 1):

The following works for your data. It uses your `GROUP BY` query as a sub-query to a `DELETE`:

```
DELETE V FROM  
@Visitor AS v
JOIN 
(
  SELECT
    RegDate,
    MIN(Visitors) MinVisitors,
    MAX(Visitors) MaxVisitors
  FROM
    @Visitor AS V
  GROUP BY
    RegDate
) T  ON 
  v.RegDate = T.RegDate 
  AND V.Visitors <> T.MinVisitors 
  AND V.Visitors <> T.MaxVisitors
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But it doesn't work to me.
I have 184,253 row(s) and only 1,400 rows has been deleted.

Comment: In which way does it not work? My tests were successful. Without further information I can't help you.

Comment: I use the solution you provided to reduce BLE scanner data to first and last record per address and it works perfectly! Many thanks!